# Why am i receiving so many warnings about peer dependencies when using Yarn?

Tags: firebase, react-native, yarnpkg-v2, geofirestore, peer-dependencies

I have just started using Yarn for the first time in a bare react native project. I started adding all dependencies that I need one-by-one. When I ran this one `yarn add geofirestore`, it showed many warnings after adding it:

[image]

Now, every time I run a new command to add another dependencies I see the same warnings.
I am not sure what to do, or if I have to do something about it. It just seems like I shouldnt ignore.